# How to get properties of attachment file in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

I'm using JSOM to get the attachment file from SharePoint. These are my lines of code:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var oListActiveMatter = web.get_lists().getByTitle("ABC List");
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();    
var viewXml = String.format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ABCNumber' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", "1232");
camlQuery.set_viewXml(viewXml);
var oListItems = oListActiveMatter.getItems(camlQuery);
ctx.load(oListItems);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    var oListItemEnumerators = oListItems.getEnumerator();
    while (oListItemEnumerators.moveNext()) {
        var item = oListItemEnumerators.get_current(); 
        //debugger;
        var attachmentFiles = item.get_attachmentFiles()
        ctx.load(attachmentFiles);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            debugger;
            if(attachmentFiles.get_count() > 0){
                var attachmentsItemsEnumerator = attachmentFiles.getEnumerator();
                while (attachmentsItemsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var item = attachmentsItemsEnumerator.get_current(); 
                    var fileName = item.get_fileName();
                    var filepath = item.get_path();
                    var serverPath = item.get_serverRelativePath();
                    var serverUrl = item.get_serverRelativeUrl();
                    var objetctData = item.get_objectData();
                    var typedObj = item.get_typedObject();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    console.log(oListItems.get_count());
});
```

But I don't find properties as: author, created date, type of file, etc...
How can I get them? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var oListActiveMatter = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Test");
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();    
var viewXml = String.format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ABCNumber' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", "1232");
camlQuery.set_viewXml(viewXml);
var oListItems = oListActiveMatter.getItems(camlQuery);
ctx.load(oListItems);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    var oListItemEnumerators = oListItems.getEnumerator();
    while (oListItemEnumerators.moveNext()) {
        var item = oListItemEnumerators.get_current(); 
        var createdBy = item.get_item('Author');
        var createdDate = item.get_item('Created');
        var modifiedBy = item.get_item('Editor');
        var modifiedDate = item.get_item('Modified');
        //debugger;
        var attachmentFiles = item.get_attachmentFiles();
        ctx.load(attachmentFiles);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            debugger;
            if(attachmentFiles.get_count() > 0){
                var attachmentsItemsEnumerator = attachmentFiles.getEnumerator();
                while (attachmentsItemsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var attachitem = attachmentsItemsEnumerator.get_current(); 
                    var fileName = attachitem.get_fileName();
                    var filepath = attachitem.get_path();
                    var serverPath = attachitem.get_serverRelativePath();
                    var serverUrl = attachitem.get_serverRelativeUrl();
                    var objetctData = attachitem.get_objectData();
                    var typedObj = attachitem.get_typedObject();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    console.log(oListItems.get_count());
});
```

Comment: If I login will other account and attach other file. I think it doesn't work

Comment: Works for me, just ensure that account has sufficient permission(at least read permission) on the list.

Comment: this gets the author of the LISTITEM, not of the attachment. This will often be the same person, but not always. It is stored separately, in SharePoint Designer 2013 I can see them.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to get all properties of ListItem attachments using REST API. Below is the URL for getting all info using REST API.

```
siteURL + _api/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/items?$select=AttachmentFiles,Title&$expand=AttachmentFiles
```

You can expand columns as per your requirement in REST API.

Comment: It's good idea. But I want get them with JSOM. Can you suggest any ideas for me?

Comment: Can you please include properties in load method as shown below.
Use ctx.load(attachmentFiles,'Include(Created,ContentTypes)'); instead of ctx.load(attachmentFiles); in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the details by specifying the internal names of these fields, like
`item.get_item('Editor')` will give you the who modified and `item.get_item('Author')` will give you who created the item.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: item.get_item is not a function. This function doesn't exist

Comment: The code in the answer will give you the details of the list item which contains the attachments. Write it before the comment //debugger in your code.

Comment: With the case other user can attach file, it will doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

to retrieve the Author and Created properties, you first need to retrieve the attachment as a File Object (does contain an Author property) instead of as an Attachment Object (doesn't contain an Author property)

In PNP Powershell you would do this as follows:

```
foreach ($attachment in $attachments){
    $file = Get-PnPFile -Url $attachment.ServerRelativeUrl -AsFileObject
    Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $file -Property Author, TimeCreated
    write-host $file.Author
    write-host $file.TimeCreated
}
```

More information:

[Attachment Class definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.attachment?view=sharepoint-csom)

[File Class definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file?view=sharepoint-csom)